# How To publish APP Packeg withuot App Store after development iphone/ipad application

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator, app-store

Is there any way to publish an iPhone/iPad application to the App Store without an account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do that. You need to have an account in iTunes Connect to at least test the app on device

Comment: also, you can publish to Cydia, but you will need to modify your SDK a little

Answer (score 1):

Publish for public access? **No.**
Publish within enterprises? **Yes.**
Publishing for testing purposes to a limited number of devices (ad hoc distribution)? **Yes.**
Publish for access on jailbroken devices only (via cydia store for example)? **Yes.**